# Xamarin Android NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm having trouble passing data between activities right now. After looking at a lot of tutorials I can't seem to figure out why I am getting a System Null Reference Exception. Here is the code for the first activity. It allows the user to input some text. Then upon pressing the button it should pass the string to the next activity:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content;

namespace DiagnosticProjFive
{
    [Activity(Label = "DiagnosticProjFive", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        Button button;
        EditText editText;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.toNextScreen);
            editText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.enterWords);

            button.Click += delegate
            {
                var enteredStrTxt = editText.Text;
                string enteredStr = enteredStrTxt.ToString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(screenTwo));
                intent.PutExtra("Extra", enteredStr);
                this.StartActivity(intent);

            };
        }
    }
}
```

The next activity. It should get the text from the previous activity and set the TextView to the inputted text:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace DiagnosticProjFive
{
    [Activity(Label = "screenTwo")]
    public class screenTwo : Activity
    {
        TextView label;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            label = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            label.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("Extra");
        }
    }
}
```

XML Source for Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/enterWords" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toNextScreen" />
</LinearLayout>
```

XML Source for screenTwo.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you try debug and see where the `Null Reference` is ocurring ?

Comment: Yes, it's occurring at the label.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("Extra"); line. The first screen works fine, but when I press the button to go to the next activity the screen turns black and the exception shows up. Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. occurred

Comment: Well that's cause label is `null`. Are you sure you have a `TextView ` called textView1 in your `screenActivity` xml ? Post the xml if you have doubts

Comment: Yes. Just posted the xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't seem to figure out why I am getting a System Null Reference Exception

You didn't set a layout for your `screenTwo`, that's why you get a System Null
Reference Exception.

### Solution :

Use `SetContentView()` method to add a layout for your `screenTwo` `Activity` :

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

      SetContentView(Resource.Layout.screenTwo); // <-- Add this line

      label = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
      label.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("Extra");
 }
```

Comment: @NovicePolymath, happy coding. : )